# Increment Database Table Names

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm looking to create a PHP script that creates a new table within a database that would be tied to a label and then within the table there would be rows of data relating to the status of the label. However, I'm not sure how I can get the PHP script (or MySQL) to increment the name of the table. All I can find is a lot of detail on auto incrementing columns for rows.

Thoughts?

Comment: sounds like a bad design. generally speaking, anything which calls for new tables with sequential names can be done with a SINGLE table and some extra fields to store whatever you'd have named the tables as. There are very few valid cases for dynamic table names.

Comment: Do you actually need a new table for each label? Couldn't you have one table, and include `label` as a column?

Comment: Ideally your application shouldn't even be _allowed_ to modify the schema of the database.  The application should access the database with the _minimal_ set of permissions possible.  (Basically it should be able to insert/update/delete and that's about it.  Maybe not even delete if you use a soft-delete method and retain the actual records.)

Comment: I thought it would be cleaner to do this with separate tables but it sounds like that's a no-go (probably why I couldn't find anything regarding this technique, haha.) Doing this in one table sounds like an OK alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. If you have scripts that, during the project live phase, create and delete regular tables, more often than not it is an indicator of bad design.

If you're keen on OOP, you may consider a table like a Class definition, and each row as an object (or an entity, if you wish) - i know it is a stretch, but it has some similarities.

Take some time to read about database normalization and database design, this project and everyone after this will benefit much more than spending time to research a working solution for the current problem you are facing.